# Flask 404 errors when deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Flask application that works fine using the development webserver and uwsgi but when deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk all of my externally defined routes 404.

I'm using the larger application structure recommended here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/

So I have an application.py that looks like this:

```
import settings
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object(settings)

application = app

#Ignore not used -> this pulls the views into the main app.
#see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/
import messages.views

#more imported applications here

@application.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    #health check endpoint.
    return "hi"
```

The hello method within application.py correctly returns 200, but the calls within message.views all return 404s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a test I decided to rename my application.py file to app.py and create a new application.py file with the following contents:

```
from app import app as application
```

This fixed the issue! I can now access all of my endpoints correctly.

Unfortunately I still don't understand what is wrong with the original setup.

Comment: This solved my case!, but I don't understand why. Two weeks ago I tried to deploy using application.py without app.py and it works fine. The code has changed since two weeks, but still not clear why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/ documentation in a flask app architecture like a package you get a directory structure that looks like :

```
    /yourapplication
        /yourapplication
            /__init__.py
            /static
                /style.css
            /templates
                layout.html
                index.html
                login.html
            /views
                /__init_.py
        ... 
    ...
```

And you put most of your code withing you `__init__.py` files so that you can call your views and application as modules of your package.

But as mentioned here you are still using application.py file which doesn't seems to be a part of package.
Also While working in a architecture like this you need to be very careful about circular imports as mentioned on the same link near the end of the webpage.

Comment: saying that putting most of your code in `__init__.py` is not fair. you can go ahead and make it modular buy adding muliples files in a module and importing all of them into the `__init__.py` file and then import the module. eg. you can have many different views in admin.py ,users.py etc and then importing all into `__init__.py` of views folder.

Comment: pygoku - I've read through that section of flask and I'm pretty sure my application structure is correct.  As I noted, the imports work perfectly running with the flask development server and also when running via uwsgi (proxied through nginx).  Its only when I pull this into AWS elastic beanstalk (serving via mod_wsgi) that I get 404s.  Additionally there are no errors, and the files are definitely being imported as app.logger lines in the root of the message/views.py file are being put into the logs.